# Does deleting an unordered_map element also release the malloc memory assigned to that unordered_map element?

Tags: c++

Does deleting an unordered_map element also release the malloc memory assigned to that unordered_map element. I was under the impression it does not. Please see the difference in two scenarios.

```
struct sdata{
    unsigned pid;
    unsigned long start;
    unsigned long end;
};


int main(){
    std::unordered_map<unsigned,struct sdata*> ht;
    ht[0] = (struct sdata*)malloc(sizeof(struct sdata));
    ht[1] = (struct sdata*)malloc(sizeof(struct sdata));
    ht[2] = (struct sdata*)malloc(sizeof(struct sdata));
    for (int i=0; i< 3; i++){
         ht[i]->start = i;
         ht[i]->end = i+1;
    }
    struct sdata *temp = ht[1];
    delete ht[1];
    //temp->start = 100;
    std::cout<<"start: "<<temp->start<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"end: "<<temp->end<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

After delete ht[1], temp->start printed a garbage value, and obvious removing the delete values printed are correct.

And surprisingly, after delete, if I access the temp->start by assigning 100 to it
(commented line in code), the value printed by temp->start is correct.

Can anyone please help me to understand this behavior of **unordered_map**
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating with `malloc` _at all_ in C++?

Comment: malloc goes with free, new with delete, new[] with delete[]. It is not valid to mix & match between them.

Comment: Because this is C++ and not C, you also do not need to specify `struct sdata` but can rather just use `sdata`.

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: If you release ownership of memory & then try to access it - that's undefined behavior. Don't do it. Anything can happen. The big scary new owner of the memory could show up and attempt to shoot you in the foot.

Comment: @Chris to be honest , I am C guy working mainly on linux kernel changes for my thesis work, I switched to c++ to use a simulator tool, this code piece is what i did there, I am still in the hand of C, sorry about that

Comment: And to your actual question, NO. unordered_map has no way of knowing how the memory was obtained or whose responsibility its management is. Not its job. For that look into smart pointers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : sorry about that, I am being a C person, I thought C experts also could help me out here,

Comment: @AviBerger Thanks for the comment, I will look into smart pointers

Comment: Best to treat C and C++ as they are: two distinct programming languages.

Comment: Anything and everything could happen as a result of this. Outcomes of undefined behaviour include you get what you expect, the program aborts, or maybe the computer spontaneously generates a Rise of Skywalker that doesn't suck. The possibilities are limitless.